# Loading a CRL assembly in SQL Server 2005: The given assembly name or codebase was invalid. (Exception from HRESULT: 0x80131047)

Tags: c#, sql, sql-server-2005, clr, .net-assembly

I've written a C# DLL which I need to call from a stored procedure.

I've got errors through ALL the steps I did, and managed to solve them. But now I'm so tired of errors that I had to resort here and ask. I can't solve this one. Every little step I made in installing this .DLL into SQL Server, I got tons of errors to solve.

Here's the C# code of the program (compiled as Class Library to get the DLL):

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using System.Net;
using System.Xml;
using System.IO;
using System.Data;
using System.Data.SqlClient;
using System.Data.SqlTypes;
using Microsoft.SqlServer.Server;

namespace WebServiceVatEuropa
{
    public class WebServiceVatEuropaClass
    {
        #region "Default Constructor"
        public WebServiceVatEuropaClass()
        {

        }
        #endregion

        [SqlProcedure]
        public static void check(string country, string vatNum)
        {
            bool valid;
            string name;
            string address;
            checkVatService vatchecker = new checkVatService();
            vatchecker.checkVat(ref country, ref vatNum, out valid, out name, out address);
        }
    }
}
```

Which is using another free library provided at the european vat checking webservice ([Link to webservice](http://ec.europa.eu/taxation_customs/vies/checkVatService.wsdl)) and uses their library ([Library code](http://pastebin.com/KwBxPZPa)) (this code is long and complex, you can just read mine I guess.

Well. I create the stored procedure (I had many problems here, many errors and so on, but now it works) with this code in SQL Server Management Studio:

```
CREATE PROCEDURE VAT_CHECKER
@Naz_codi nvarchar(2),
@vatNum nvarchar(max)
AS EXTERNAL NAME WebServiceVatEuropaClass.[WebServiceVatEuropa.WebServiceVatEuropaClass].[check]
GO
```

And then in the db I have:

1. enabled the clr with the code from msn

   ```
   sp_configure 'show advanced options', 1;
   GO
   RECONFIGURE;
   GO
   sp_configure 'clr enabled', 1;
   GO
   RECONFIGURE;
   GO
   ```
2. changed the db owner to sa
3. registered the assembly with this code

   ```
   CREATE ASSEMBLY [WebServiceVatEuropaClass] --AUTHORIZATION [mydb\administrator]
   FROM 'C:\Upload\WebServiceVatEuropa.dll'
   --WITH PERMISSION_SET = SAFE
   WITH PERMISSION_SET = UNSAFE
   --WITH PERMISSION_SET = EXTERNAL_ACCESS
   ```

Then when I launch

```
EXEC VAT_CHECKER 'IT','10050721009'
```

I get  this error:

> An error occurred in the Microsoft .NET Framework while trying to load assembly id 65545. The server may be running out of resources, or
>   the assembly may not be trusted with PERMISSION_SET = EXTERNAL_ACCESS
>   or UNSAFE. Run the query again, or check documentation to see how to
>   solve the assembly trust issues. For more information about this
>   error:  System.IO.FileLoadException: Could not load file or assembly
>   'webservicevateuropa, Version=0.0.0.0, Culture=neutral,
>   PublicKeyToken=null' or one of its dependencies. The given assembly
>   name or codebase was invalid. (Exception from HRESULT: 0x80131047)
>
> System.IO.FileLoadException:
>   at System.Reflection.Assembly._nLoad(AssemblyName fileName, String
>   codeBase, Evidence assemblySecurity, Assembly locationHint,
>   StackCrawlMark& stackMark, Boolean throwOnFileNotFound, Boolean
>   forIntrospection)
>   at System.Reflection.Assembly.InternalLoad(AssemblyName assemblyRef,
>   Evidence assemblySecurity, StackCrawlMark& stackMark, Boolean
>   forIntrospection)
>   at System.Reflection.Assembly.InternalLoad(String assemblyString, Evidence assemblySecurity, StackCrawlMark& stackMark, Boolean forIntrospection)
>   at System.Reflection.Assembly.Load(String assemblyString)

What it could be? I can't find anything to fix it...

Comment: When you want to properly format code snippets inside a bulleted (or numbered) list, you need to indent it by **8 spaces** (not just 4)

Comment: For anyone else looking for the answer to this, I found a combination of this question and http://stackoverflow.com/q/2193720/192999 helped me out. Cheers.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

So, at long last, I managed to solve the problem (and I couldn't believe it).

Here's what I did:

-The code remained mostly the same as above.

-I was trying to deploy the dll on a SQL server 2005 on a remote desktop machine, but I was compiling it locally with Visual Studio 2010. Maybe this was an issue, OR MAYBE NOT. But I switched to a Visual Studio 2008 copy installed on the remote desktop machine. I read on some sites that different target architecture compilation settings in Visual Studio can generate issues similar to mine.

-As I said, at every step I made in this task of deploying this assembly to an instance of SQL Server, I got an error. And this time it was no different. After I compiled it on the remote desktop machine, it gave another error about XmlSerialization.

**NOTE:** The particular reason because **I NEEDED** the XmlSerializers was because I was consuming a webservice which used Xml and C# Xml objects to manipulate data, therefore Xml was involved in the program. I don't know whether you need XmlSerializers in other situations or not, but in this particular case I needed it otherwise SQL server would give me exoteric errors.

The solution for this particular issue is explained here:

[Xml Serialization issues](http://www.cstruter.com/blog/320)

I solved by generating this extra dll by changing the compilation settings like shown in the article.

-This ends what I had to do in Visual Studio.

Now it starts the SQL Part:

- I had to create an assembly for both my own DLL, and for the XmlSerialization one.

  ```
  CREATE ASSEMBLY [WebServiceVatEuropaClass] --AUTHORIZATION [mydb\administrator]
  FROM 'C:\Upload\WebServiceVatEuropa.dll'
  --WITH PERMISSION_SET = SAFE
  WITH PERMISSION_SET = UNSAFE
  --WITH PERMISSION_SET = EXTERNAL_ACCESS



  CREATE ASSEMBLY [WebServiceVatEuropaClassXmlSerializers] --AUTHORIZATION [mydb\administrator]
  FROM 'C:\Upload\WebServiceVatEuropa.XmlSerializers.dll'
  --WITH PERMISSION_SET = SAFE
  WITH PERMISSION_SET = UNSAFE
  --WITH PERMISSION_SET = EXTERNAL_ACCESS
  ```

**NOTE: Probably since the problem was not permissions (though Sql server was giving me totally misleading SAFE/EXTERNAL permission error messages) it may be sufficient to set the assembly permission as EXTERNAL instead of UNSAFE. I say this just because you might not want to allow UNSAFE permission if not strictly needed, as this whole process is pretty unsecure (if I documented myself well by reading on the internet) and even with asymmetric keys someone could replace your assemblies**

then I created the Stored procedure for calling (same code as above in the question) the assembly and this time when I called the EXEC, IT WORKED!

Hope this will be useful for someone else having the same problem.

Answer (score 1):

The error message basically tells you all - since your assembly is reaching out and accesses an external web service, you **must** configure it as `EXTERNAL_ACCESS`.

You're not showing just how you're creating the assembly in your SQL Server - but basically, you need to use something like:

```
CREATE ASSEMBLY assembly_name
FROM ...(your assembly).....
WITH PERMISSION_SET = { EXTERNAL_ACCESS }
```

Did you do it like this? If not: please try again with the `EXTERNAL_ACCESS` permission set!

See the [MSDN documentation on Code Access Security](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms345101.aspx) for more details

Comment: Added what I use to create the clr (Actually I don't create it, the DBA makes all the sql job). It seems it's already set to external access. When I firstly documented myself about adding CLR Assemblies in Sql 2005, I had read the lot of the msdn related articles. So what I did is basically following they're guides. DBA tells me that probably

UNSAFE is even higher in level than EXTERNAL ACCESS,

therefore, putting it to unsafe should include EXTERNAL ACCESS, but he's not sure.

You know anything about this particular issue? Meanwhile I read msdn articles

Comment: I create it as UNSAFE. Quoting from MSDN:

UNSAFE
UNSAFE allows assemblies unrestricted access to resources, both within and outside SQL Server. Code executing from within an UNSAFE assembly can also call unmanaged code.

So it should also give EXTERNAL_ACCESS...